# Double Wick Rotation of de Sitter Metric with Closed Slicing

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, wick-rotation, de-sitter-spacetime

The de Sitter spacetime (with closed spherically symmetric slicing) has the metric $$\text{d}s^2 = -\text{d}t^2 + \alpha^2\cosh(t/\alpha)^2\text{d}\Omega_{d-1}^2$$
where $\text{d}\Omega_{d-1}^2$ is the standard metric on the $(d-1)$-dimensional sphere with unit radius. My question is; if one Wick rotates the time coordinate and the $S^1\subset S^{d-1}$ coordinate simultaneously, then what is the resulting spacetime?
As a concrete example, let $d=3$. Then, I am thinking of the following metric obtained from $t\to i(\tau+\pi)$ and, say $\phi\in(0,2\pi]$ in $S^{d-1}$, goes to $\phi\to i\tilde{t}$,

$$\begin{align}\text{d}s^2 &= \text{d}\tau^2 + \alpha^2\sin(t/\alpha)^2\left(\text{d}\theta^2 - \sin(\theta)^2 \text{d}\tilde{t}^2\right)
\end{align}$$

The spacetime is still de Sitter since the scalar curvature is constant. Perhaps this spacetime is a de Sitter soliton? I am aware of the de Sitter bubble of nothing but this requires a horizon.